# Please explain this javascript comma syntax commonly used to define Dragging RaphaelJs

Tags: javascript, syntax, raphael

Here is the "dragger" defined in the raphaeljs [graffle](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) example.

```
var dragger = function () {
this.ox = this.type == "rect" ? this.attr("x") : this.attr("cx");
this.oy = this.type == "rect" ? this.attr("y") : this.attr("cy");
this.animate({"fill-opacity": .2}, 500);
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    var att = this.type == "rect" ? {x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy} : {cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy};
    this.attr(att);
    for (var i = connections.length; i--;) {
        r.connection(connections[i]);
    }
    r.safari();
},
up = function () {
    this.animate({"fill-opacity": 0}, 500);
},
r = Raphael("holder", 640, 480),
connections = [],
shapes = [  r.ellipse(190, 100, 30, 20),
            r.rect(290, 80, 60, 40, 10),
            r.rect(290, 180, 60, 40, 2),
            r.ellipse(450, 100, 20, 20)
        ];
```

Am I right that:

1. That move, up, r, connections and shapes are INDEPENDENT variables? I.e. NOT methods/ attributes of dragger?
2. This is just a sequential definition of variables at an equivalent scope?

Are move, up, etc. considered to have been declared using the var keyword?

Thanks for the help. Love and peace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just like a long series of `var` statements.

Similar, and easier to read:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

In this case I definitely would NOT use this syntax, and would instead use a separate line for each variable.  It's really hard to read as is.

In short: yes, you are right on both counts.  This is exactly the same as

```
var dragger = ...;
var move = ...;
var up = ....;
...
```

except it's a pain to read.  The extra commas hiding between declarations are what tie the whole thing together into the `var` statement.

Comment: That's what i thought. Since i have been concentrating on Python lately, I spent a whole bunch of time trying to figure out if move & up, etc. were methods of dragger. Thanks for the response, Riley.

Comment: Just as an aside, I think Douglas Crockford would seriously disagree with not using this var syntax.  In JavaScript, there is only function scope.  Meaning a variable introduced anywhere in a function is visible everywhere in a function.  Because JavaScript doesn't have block scope, it's actually safer to use a single var statement.  Take a read of Crockford's JavaScript code conventions; it's a good read:  http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Jon. What do you/Douglas mean by "safer"? Is it worth sacrificing readability? On Douglas' site he saidthe following. "It is preferred that each variable be given its own line and comment. They should be listed in alphabetical order.      `var currentEntry; // currently selected table entry
var level;        // indentation level
var size;`

Comment: I think his main point is to code defensively.  JavaScript has a lot of quirks and using JSLint for code quality will greatly reduce the amount of odd behavior you may encounter.  As far as variables, he's saying to go with:  var a = null, b = null, c = null, ... etc where each variable is on its own line, but you still declare all of your variables at the top of the function, once.

Comment: @Jon, I have to disagree with your reading of your link ~ it seems clear that he thinks each variable should have its own `var` (as in each of his examples) and he explicitly states that there should be at most one statement per line, and that every simple statement should be followed by a semicolon.

Comment: @RileyLark You're right, I must have read it wrong.  However, if you use JSLint, you will receive errors for not combining var statements into one.  So I'm curious why the two differ.